# Java FX8 HLS Audio Stream

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, http-live-streaming

Trying this whole morning and cannot get it to work.

Works with sample .flv source, but cannot get it to play live radio.

Also tried putting stream into .m3u8 file, to no avail.

```
Media media;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
MediaView mediaView;

String source = "http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv";
String sourcelive = "http://newyorkcity.radiostreamlive.com/radionylive_128";

media = new Media(sourcelive);
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);

mediaPlayer.setOnReady(() -> {
    label.setText("Ready");
        mediaPlayer.play();
    });
```

**.setOnReady** never fires for the live stream.

Must be missing sth obvious here.

*javafx.runtime.version=8.0.60
javafx.runtime.build=b27*

Comment: [JavaFX 8 media package javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) has information on supported containers, encoding and protocols for media playback.  Ensure that the media you are testing conforms to those.  Add additional error handling as per the javadoc example.

Comment: For anyone else looking, the HLS seemed to be the solution, HTTP live streams do not work.